# How to replace AsyncTask with doAsync

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I am retriving all documents from firestore and storing it in a ArrayList with a each element being a custom dataType. The data retriving process takes a little time and so I want to make the listView after the data has been retrived. I have used AsyncTask before and would have used the onPostExectue function but I came to know about doAsync in kotlin and wanted to gitve it a try.

Can someone guide me how to do it?

This is the function to get Data

```
    fun initFirestore(): ArrayList<MetaData>{
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this@MainActivity)
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val returnData: ArrayList<MetaData> = ArrayList()
        db.collection("name_of_collection")
                .orderBy("id")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        for (document in task.result) {
                            val data = document.data
                            returnData.add(MetaData(data["name"].toString(), data["artist"].toString(), data["url"].toString()))
//                            Log.d("Test", document.id + " => " + data)
                        }
                    } else {
//                        Log.d("Test", "Error getting documents: ", task.exception)
                    }
                }
        return returnData
    }
```

The log shows the correct data. And I am calling it from another function

```
fun getSongs(){
        doAsync {
            val test = initFirestore()

            onComplete {
                Log.v("Test","$test")
            }

            uiThread {
                Log.v("A","$test")
            }
        }
    }
```

Both log here return empty list

Comment: If you go down that route, you're probably better off with suspending functions once Kotlin 1.3 comes out.

Comment: I added my code to give a better idea. And do I have to use AsyncTask for this before kotlin 1.3 comes out?